# добавить перменную в html тег

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, cgi

Запускаю, скрипт в вебе, в частности CGI, вроде всё ок, тег `<br>` даже работает. Много вариантов уже перепробовал не могу понять как мне переменные: `path[11:23]` и `mtime1` добавить к тегу таблицы, хочется что бы вывод `path[11:23]` и `mtime1` был ровненький на странице. А не в разнобой как сейчас.

```
    #! /usr/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import cgi, os
    import time
    import datetime as dt
    import datetime

    print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    print ("<H1>DGFDGFDG</H1>")

        .....

    print("<br>" + path[11:23], mtime1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Если ты выводишь данные, но они "лежат криво", ищи проблему в стилях. Но похоже что к строке "br" ты прибавляешь переменную path[11:23], что даст тебе строку 'brpath[11:23]', получается что ты перенесешься на новую сроку и там отрисуешь эту переменную. Если у тебя таблица, и значения должны быть в ячейках, сделай вывод в виде многострочного текста:

```
some_string = '''
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{0}</td>
        <td>{1}</td>
        <td>{2}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
'''.format(a,b,c)

print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print(some_string)
```

Comment: В данном случае `<br>` работает как тег, он не прибавляется, а переносит строку.
Вот мой полный пример скрипта: https://ibb.co/RNgKn3b Если честно твой пример тоже не понял) Если я уберу `<br>` у меня будет вывод сплошняком в одну строку

Comment: В твоем коде нет таблицы... есть построчный вывод данных, чтобы вывод  "был ровненький" попробуй path[11:23] поменять на path[0:] тогда будет отображаться вся информация